# Perform a script automatically every <time a day I set>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to run for example a synchronizing ruby script (in rails action if it's possible) between two databases every day at 3AM. It'd would be nice to have those times stored in a database, because if the synchonization fails I'd like to set it to try it again in an hour (and in database I can easily change it to every day at 5AM if I'd wanted to, even other admins in administration of my application). I would like to have the script in one of actions in my Rails application, so I can create a page in administration where just by clicking the link the script would run (not necessary, it can be in a separate Ruby file, which action would call eventually, but it would be nicer to have it as actions in a dedicated controller, because I'll have many scripts like this one and I just like having similar things in a one place). Is this somehow possible without things-I-dont-know-anything-about-yet like cron?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to deal directly with cron, have a look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It provides a nice syntax for writing cron jobs:

```
every :hour do
  runner "MyModel.do_something"
end
```

Comment: Oh, this looks exactly like the way I wanted to do it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a task scheduler to do this.

On Windows, the standard scheduler is called [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

On Linux, the standard scheduler is called [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Both are trivially simple to use. If you're writing Ruby code, you can schedule a task.

For example, to schedule a command to run every hour of every day with `cron`, type `crontab -e`, and add this line:

```
0 3 * * * /command/to/run
```

To have it run every hour, so that you can have it check a database to see if it should do something:

```
0 * * * * /command/to/run
```